# Combinatoric expression for $V_n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I just want to know how to prove this passage bellow\begin{align*}
G(z)&=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}U_{i}z^{i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}     \sum_{k_0+k_1+\dots+k_{r-1}=n}\binom{n}{k_0,k_1,\dots,k_{r-1}}a_0^{k_0}a_1^{k_1} \dots a_{r-1}^{k_{r-1}} z^{{k_0+2k_1+\dots+rk_{r-1}}},\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}V_{n}z^{n}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}U_{i}z^{i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n      \sum_{k_0+2k_1+\dots+rk_{r-1}=n}\binom{k_0+k_1+\dots+k_{r-1}}{k_0,k_1,\dots,k_{r-1}}a_0^{k_0}a_1^{k_1} \dots a_{r-1}^{k_{r-1}},
\end{align*} where G is generating function for sequence $V_n$.

Comment: Do you have any context for this?

Comment: Did you mean to have no variable $i$ in the inner sums?  What is $U_i$? This is not very clear.

Comment: We don't have no variable $i$ in the inner sums. We defined $U_i$ as function of $V_ {0} ,V_ {1},\dots,V_{r-1}$ (initial condition) for sequence $(V_n)$ by $$U_{i}=V_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{i}a_{j-1}V_{i-j}$$ .

Comment: Let $ a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{r-1}  $ $ (r\geqslant 2)$ complex numbers 
 with $a_{r-1}\neq 0 $ . For any sequence of complex numbers $ (\alpha_ {0} ,\dots,\alpha_{r-1} ) $ . Using the $r$-th order linear recurrence:\begin{equation}
 V_{n+1}=a_{0}V{_n}+\dots+a_{r-1}V_{n-r+1}, ~pour ~tout ~~n\geqslant{r-1}\\\\  
\end{equation}
 and$$
V_0=\alpha_{0},~ V_1=\alpha_{1} ~,\ldots, ~ V_{r-1}=\alpha_{r-1},
$$ we  can  use the multinomial theorem to obtain a formula for $V_n$ that is a function of (i.e. , the elmentary  symmetric function of) $ a_0,a_1,\dots,a_{r-1}  $

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
**Hint:**
$$
z^{k_{0} + 2k_{1} + \cdots + r\,k_{r - 1}} =
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}z^{\ell}
\delta_{\ell,k_{0} + 2k_{1} + \cdots + r\,k_{r - 1}}
$$
Now, you can "*freely*" exchange the $\displaystyle\ell$-sum which
"*isolate*" the term $\displaystyle z^{\ell}$ to the left.
\begin{align}
\mrm{G}\pars{z} & \equiv
\sum_{i = 0}^{r - 1}U_{i}z^{i}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{k_{0} + \cdots + k_{r-1} = n}
{n \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_1}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,z^{k_{0} + 2k_{1} + \cdots + rk_{r - 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{r - 1}U_{i}z^{i}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\
\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = n}
{n \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_1}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\sum_{m = i}^{\infty}z^{m - i}\,
\delta_{m,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{r - 1}U_{i}\sum_{m = i}^{\infty}z^{m}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\
\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = n}
{n \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_1}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\delta_{m,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{i \leq r - 1}U_{i}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}z^{m}\bracks{m \geq i}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\
\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = n}
{n \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\delta_{m,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}z^{m}\sum_{i = 0}^{\min\braces{\!m,r - 1\!}}U_{i}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = n}
{n \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\delta_{m,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}V_{n}z^{n}
\end{align}
I already exchanged the $\ds{m\ \mbox{and}\ n}$
indexes $\ds{\pars{~m \leftrightarrow n~}}$ to get closer to the OP proposed expression. Then,
\begin{align}
V_{n} & \equiv
\sum_{i = 0}^{\min\braces{\!n,r - 1\!}}U_{i}
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = m}
{m \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\delta_{n,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}}
\end{align}
The *inner sum* is $\ds{i}$-*independent* such that
\begin{align}
&\bbx{V_{n} =
\pars{\sum_{i = 0}^{\min\braces{\!n,r - 1\!}}U_{i}}\bracks{%
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1} = m}
{m \choose k_{0},\ldots,k_{r - 1}}a_{0}^{k_0}a_{1}^{k_{1}}\ldots
a_{r - 1}^{k_{r - 1}}\,\delta_{n,\sum_{j = 0}^{r - 1}\pars{j + 1}k_{j}}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Felix for your answer but It's not very clear.

Comment: @ZakariaZH Thanks. I did a 'little bit' more.